# Why does an instance method have this type in Swift?

Tags: swift, types

Given this code:

```
struct Foo {
    func f() {}
}

let f = Foo.f // (Foo) -> () -> ()
```

Why does `f` have the type `(Foo) -> () -> ()` and not `(Foo) -> ()`? Wouldn’t it make sense for instance methods like `Foo.f` to be directly interchangeable with free functions of type `(Foo) -> …`?

Comment: Related: [Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `f` have the type `(Foo) -> () -> ()` and not `(Foo) -> ()`?

That's just currently how unapplied instance method references are implemented; they're curried functions that follow the model of "give me an instance, and I'll give you back a partially-applied instance method" (partially applied with that instance).

However this is problematic in some areas, firstly because it's generally more useful for them to be of the form `(Self, Args...) -> Ret`, but also more importantly because it because it leads to issues around `mutating` methods. These end up looking like `(inout Self) -> (Args...) -> Ret` with the current system, which is problematic because the window of mutation for `inout` only lasts for the duration of the call.

This means the following currently compiles, but is actually *undefined behaviour:*

```
struct S {
  var i: Int

  mutating func increment() {
    i += 1
  }
}

var s = S(i: 0)
let unappliedIncrement = S.increment
let increment = unappliedIncrement(&s)
increment() // undefined behaviour
```

These are the main motivations behind [SE-0042](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0042-flatten-method-types.md), which will change unapplied instance method references from being of the form `(Self) -> (Args...) -> Ret` to being of the form
 `(Self, Args...) -> Ret` (and with `inout`, `Self` will be `inout Self` – allowing the mutation of the instance without UB).

This proposal is yet to be implemented, but once it is, assuming empty parameter lists get flattened out (so you don't end up with a trailing `Void` parameter), `Foo.f` will indeed be of type
 `(Foo) -> Void`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because, by saying this:

```
let f = Foo.f
```

you've described `f` as a *class* method, `Foo.f`. But in your declaration of Foo, `f` is an *instance* method. You have thus accidentally discovered the deep dark secret that instance methods are class methods in disguise; you are seeing the signature of the secret class method.

If you had said

```
let f = Foo().f
```

you would have gotten the expected result.

Comment: I get the fact that instance methods and class methods are quite interchangeable – you could say that an instance method is a class method with a first, hidden argument already supplied. But when I translate this into types, I would say that a class method on a type `Foo` is `T -> U` and an instance method is `Foo -> T -> U`. But in reality the instance method is `Foo -> () -> T -> U`. And it’s the extra `()` that I don’t get.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking now. If you understand that an instance method is a curried class method, then you know the answer to your own question.

Comment: I guess what confuses me is that I would expect to be able to freely go from free functions to instance functions. In other words, when I have an instance method `String.uppercased: () -> String`, I would expect `f = String.uppercased` to have type `String -> String` (“a function that takes a string and returns a string”), but there’s an extra `()` in there (“a function that takes a string and returns a function that takes void and returns a string”).