# How to define a Singleton in Swift

Tags: swift, singleton, static-methods

I'm defining a Singleton with this code:

```
class MySingleton {

    static let instance = MySingleton()

    private init() {}

    func example(myParameter:String) {

    }
}
```

Which seems to work ok as I can do the following call correctly:

```
MySingleton.instance.example(myParameter:"a string")
```

The strange behavior is that I can also do this one:

```
MySingleton.example(self: MySingleton.instance)
```

I know I have defined a static property to create the Singleton but the function `example` is not static, so why can I call it from class level? Also, notice the parameter of this second call, it is not receiving the `String` parameter defined in the function but a `self` of type `MySingleton`.

As I have seen this doesn't happen if the function is defined as private, but obviously I need it public for proper use so, what am I defining wrongly?

Comment: https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47316599.

Comment: Did you copy the code correctly? `MySingleton.example(self: MySingleton)` does not compile in my Xcode 11. Perhaps you meant `MySingleton.example(MySingleton.instance)` ?

Comment: Hi @MartinR that `MySingleton` was just the class type it is required for that function, not the call itself, sorry I didn't make myself clear. Updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an instance to an instance method makes a reference to that instance method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534385/passing-an-instance-to-an-instance-method-makes-a-reference-to-that-instance-met)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Reading that I understand the origin of my problem but I don't think it totally solves my answer as what I want is a correct implementation of the singleton pattern. So then my question is, does this happen with all the Singletons in Swift (even the ones from the standard libraries)?

Comment: I don't see why this would stop your class from being a singleton, it's always the same instance being used and the function is (example(myParameter:)) is called from that instance

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm not concerned about the class being a singleton, it is and is working well. My concern is that this project is a library intended to be used by others and that singleton is a public one, so I think it may mislead other developers when they use it. However, I have checked some official classes from Apple that are singletons and they behave the same way so I suppose there's no problem.

Comment: I think you need to assume that if a user does `MySingleton.example(self: MySingleton.instance)` he/she has a reason for it and also knows what the code does.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I guess so, then I suppose the question is answered. I don't really know if this should be posted and considered as new content (different from the links above) or if it should be closed, so answer if you want or else I will delete it. Thanks.

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela If you got the answer you need in comments, why not write up an answer yourself? You can accept it, and then it'll be there to help future developers who have a similar question. Don't delete your question and hide the knowledge that you just gained.

Comment: Hi @Caleb, if I suggest it is because some comments point out that the question has already been answered in other posts and also this post has been downvoted. I don't think it's the same situation but seeing that I'm the only one I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it has been said that this question is already answered in SO I think there are some differences that make this one unique and that's why I'm going to answer it.

My implementation of the Singleton is totally correct and the problem that was concerning me is described, as Martin R has said in the comments, [here](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/). It is known as “Curried” Functions, as that link will tell you far more than I can.

In regard to the singletons there's no way, as far as I have discovered, to hide these "class" methods. However, it is also true we shouldn't worry much about it as some official classes (the ones made by Apple) that uses singletons also show this same behavior. Here we have some examples in case you want to check:

- UserDefaults.standard
- FileManager.default
- URLSession.shared
- OperationQueue.main
- UIApplication.shared

So basically, if you're just making a singleton (and you aren't familiar with curried functions) and you see this behavior, don't worry about it, it is the correct way to do it and there's nothing wrong in your code.